# ExecuteScalar() method is not working properly

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have the following function;

```
public int GetLoginClaim(IsValidLogin Obj)
{
    SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    SqlCommand CmdSelect = new SqlCommand("IsValidLogin", DBCon);
    CmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DBCon.Open();
    try
    {
        CmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Obj.Username);
        CmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Obj.Password);

        return (int)CmdSelect.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        CmdSelect.Dispose();
        DBCon.Close();
        DBCon.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the following stored procedure on which it depends;

```
USE [SMania]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IsValidLogin]
@UserName varchar(32),
@Password varchar(32)
As
if exists(Select * From NewClientTB Where UserName = @UserName And Password = @Password)
 return(1)
else
 return(0)
```

The stored procedure is working correctly when executed on sql server, but when called from the function i posted above, it gives error. The above function is in my data access layer. So in the stack trace, i am having the following error on the above function:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Can anyone fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try debugging and watching what variable is null?

Comment: yes, check the object and see if obj.username or obj.password is null

Comment: I didnt check, i am checking it now

Comment: Try using select instead of return
`Select 1
else
Select 0`
and in .net you can use ExecuteReader() and use data[0] value

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need different approach for SPs with return status

Check the example on this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378371(v=sql.90).aspx

If you want to use `ExecuteScalar` you need to replace `return(X)` with `select X` in SP because it "returns the first column of the first row in the result set" but there is no result set in your SP only return value.

This is how you can get return status in C#

```
CmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Obj.Username);
CmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Obj.Password);

var return_state = CmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
return_state.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

CmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (int)return_state.Value;
```

Comment: That example is probably in java. I could not get the idea how to do it in C# using ado.net

Comment: Exception disappeared but does not return 1 on successful match

Comment: I just tried this code with simplified procedure with `if(@UserName=@Password)` and it worked correctly for me. I mean it returned 1 for same values and 0 for different. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/p6sNiujC I used LinqPad to test it.